# is there any way to create a checkbox list through javascript using kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I would like to know whether is there a way to program populate my kendo checkbox list like the image below through javascript object/array because most of the online search result are creating a list at html.

[sample of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdGcE.png)

Comment: I didn't find it. In angularJS I used ng-repeat on an array and I think this is the closest way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the checkbox list rendered, then use MVVM **checked** binding:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/mvvm/elements

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/checked

If you want to render the checkbox list with JavaScript, according to some data, and check the checkboxes at the same time, then use Kendo UI **templates** and `kendo.render()`

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo#methods-render

```
<ul id="checkboxList"></ul>

<script>

var template = kendo.template("<li>" +
    "<label>" +
        "<input type='checkbox' #: isChecked ? \" checked='checked'\" : \"\"  # />" +
        "#: name #" +
    "</label>" +
"</li>");

var data = [
  { id: 1, name: "foo", isChecked: true },
  { id: 2, name: "bar", isChecked: false }
];

var html = kendo.render(template, data);
$("#checkboxList").html(html);

</script>
```

Instead of `kendo.render()`, you can alternatively use a Kendo UI **ListView** and an item template. The template definition itself can be the same.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/listview/index

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/listview#configuration-template